# Facing issue while running a code in python by using @classmethod decorator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, decorator

I am trying to run the below command in my jupyter notebook, it's working fine cuz no error showed up but also no output. But if am trying the same command in an IDE it's working fine. What can be the problem??

```
import csv

class Item:
    @classmethod 
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls): 
        with open('item.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f) #this method will read the content from csv file as a dictionary
            items = list(reader)

        for item in items:
            print(item)


Item.instantiate_from_csv()
```

I tried in jupyter, I didn't get the expected output, a list of all the items mentioned in the csv in the form of dictionary so then I tried in IDLE it worked fine and I got the expected output.

Comment: Please specify "it didn't work".

Comment: Maybe the "item.csv is located correctly within your IDE/directoy-structure but is missing in your notebook?

Comment: @RenéJahn If item.csv couldn't be opened an exception would occur

Comment: @RenéJahn yeah exactly but there is no exception and after providing an absolute path all I am getting is an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute

```
        with open('item.csv') as f:
```

the CWD, current working directory, is pretty important.

Use `os.getcwd()` to verify it is what you expect.

If it isn't, consider switching from
a relative to an absolute pathname,
that looks like `/some/where/item.csv`.

---

Your previous efforts might have accidentally
created a zero-length data file. If you notice
such a .CSV file, just delete it, so that
future attempts to read it will produce a
more informative diagnostic error message.

Comment: Thanks, @J_H  for the help it worked. I got the expected result.